# What happened to dead java thread in linux?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, exception, stability

I got a NullPointerException in my project and I would like to evaluate what is the sevirity of this issue. The exception is thrown just before the thread finished its task and going to die anyway.
My code failed to catch this excepition, so the thread is dead.

Here is a simple simulation of the situation:

```java
public class Test extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Test thread = new Test();
        thread.start();
        while(true) {
           System.out.println("I'm still here!");
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        String s = null;
        int len = s.length(); // causes NullPinterException
    }
}
```

My question is: What is going to happened to this poor thread now? Is its linux file descriptor get freed? Is there any stability or memroy issues that may occur in such kind of code?

Comment: (Note: Edited to emphasize the fact that the "system" should keep running)

Comment: Threads don't have file descriptors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handling is not different than with any other terminated thread. The one thing that happens before is the search for an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) according to the rules (specific `Thread`, `ThreadGroup`, all threads) but apart from this the "normal" cleanup procedure follows. There are no specific consequences regarding sytem resources (depending on the `Thread` implementation) or memory issues when a thread is terminated by an uncaught exception in contrast to a "normal" termination.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about threads at all. Look at your code:

```
   String s = null;
   int len = s.length();
```

When you are calling `s.length()` the `s` is indeed `null` that causes `NullPointerException`. 
Assign some value to `s` and you will get its length.

Comment: This is his question, what happens with the thread after the exception is thrown.